# Android cannot reach Restlet service running on same network

Tags: android, web-services, restlet

I am testing an Android app which is connected to my local router.  On the same WiFi network are also running some Java web services using Restlets.  I verified that the Android app can hit the service filter and even receive a response from the service filter.  However, it cannot seem to hit the Restlet service in question.

The full URL to the service is:

```
http://192.168.0.148:8080/MyApp/service/login
```

where `192.168.0.148` is the local IP address of the computer running the Restlet web services.

I have the service mapped in my Restlet `Application` class as follows:

```
router.attach("/login", LoginResource.class);
```

My `web.xml` file has the appropriate mappings to route anything with the pattern `/service/` to the Restlet servlet.

I can successfully hit this service when testing from SOAP UI using precisely the same URL I gave above.  In fact, all web services have been tested end-to-end using SOAP UI and are completely functional.

For some reason, the Android app can hit the service filter, when but when it reaches:

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

the request ends up lost in space, and nothing gets returned.

I suspect that this is largely a Reslets configuration problem, though I don't know exactly what is happening here.

Comment: Post the code you're using to connect to the server.  Do you get a timeout error?  Can you log from the server to see if the request gets there?

Comment: @nasch As I mentioned, the Android app can send and receive so long as the response is sent from the filter.  But when the filter chain is forwarded it never makes it to the `/login` service.

Answer (score 0):

I got virtually no feedback, either from the SO community or from Restlets, which actually makes sense given that everything I reported in the question is correct.  I decided to attach the Restlet sources to my IntelliJ IDE, and step through the code.  I had seen that the Tomcat logs contained a response code of `415`, and by inspecting the actual exception inside Restlets, I saw an error stating that the media type I posted was unexpected.  Upon seeing this, I immediately knew what I had done wrong, which was:

- not sending proper JSON to the login service
- not declaring the content type to be JSON in the header of the POSt
- and using Restlet services all of which expect JSON

For anyone who faces as similar problem using Restlets with JSON, the following Android code got everything working with no issues:

```
String endpoint = "http://192.168.0.148:8080/MyApp/service/login";
URL obj = new URL(endpoint);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("username", username);
json.put("password", password);
// etc.
```